# No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I haven't seen any questions addressing this error specific to the "Windows" authentication scheme. I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app hosted in IIS, and I tried to follow these instructions to set up Windows Auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x but I get the title error exception when it goes to authorize:

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to authenticate for the scheme: Windows
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)...

Specifically I have the code in my `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

services.AddMvc(opt =>
{
    var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)                       
        .Build();
    opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
});
```

And in `Configure`:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Something else that makes my situation unique is that I am targeting .NET Framework 4.7 (not .NET Core) with the following package references. Is there one that I'm missing that actually performs the authentication?

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.2" />
```

Any help with this error appreciated!

Comment: And windows auth is enabled on your site in IIS?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I am exactly looking for the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss that property to set true in your Properties/launchSettings.json;

```
"windowsAuthentication": true
```